# Tree component with table-like "cells"?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

I need to have several, separately editable "cells" for a tree node. A TreeTable is **not suitable**, as I have several node types which have different record structures.

Is there already a (preferably free) component for this? If not, do you have some implementation hints for me? Especially it would be important that I can assign different "CellRenderers" and "CellEditors" to different cells, and to be able to resize a certain cell for *all nodes* of a certain node type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, what you want is **not** a tree in a table, but a table in a tree. Am I correct ?

If so, you can take a look at [this old example in comp.lang.java.gui,](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.java.programmer/browse_thread/thread/292cfe48566ba5ca/e4cb7fb38fa2e02c?lnk=gst&q=jtable+within+jtree#e4cb7fb38fa2e02c) which achieves what you want in the most typical fashion : by using as JTree renderer a Jtable painter

Comment: You are correct, but the "tables" should have no headers and contain always just one row. Of course I would like to avoid the complexity of one full blown table model per node. But for now I check out the link you provided.

Answer (score 0):

You might look into `org.netbeans.swing.outline.Outline`, mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841582).

Comment: Hmm, that looks just like the usual TreeTable, which wouldn't work in my case (as I have different "columns" for different node types)

Comment: Ah, I see. Instead of trying to fit the details in the tree, I've used the approach mentioned here with both `JTable` and `Outline`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167452