# DefaultListSelectionModel is slow, how can I add selections faster?

Tags: java, swing, optimization, jtable

For my JTable I am using a DefaultListSelectionModel. There is a setSelectionInteral(int index0, int index1) and addSelectionInteral(int index0, int index1). These work great if I have one contiguous selection or a single selection. What if I have lots of individual or noncontinuous selections? Adding a thousand single selections is very slow. Should I be using another class to drive my JTable selections? I do not understand why I cannot supply a List of selected indexes all at once, why only intervals?

Comment: Can you amplify on the purpose of such a complex selection? An [sscce](http://sscce.org/) may be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of trying to maintain a complex state in your `ListSelectionModel`, consider storing the state in the `TableModel` and letting a renderer signify the state, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13919878/230513).

Comment: I agree (like it would matter if I didn't ;)), using selection to "highlight" cells probably isn't a good idea +1

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I welcome your insights! A custom `ListSelectionModel` _might_ be warranted, but updating a `TableModel` is easier to optimize.