# Check Boxes not able to be Selected -- They are Editable! Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have read so many questions on this website concerning this problem and I cannot find why it is still not working.

**The Problem:**

I made a `JTable` to be displayed inside a `JScrollPane`. The `JTable` is constructed as follows:

```
table = new JTable(new DataTableModel());
```

As you can see, I use a custom `AbstractDataModel` called `DataTableModel`. Now, when I display this **the checkboxes appear, but they are not able to be selected**. They are editable as you can see below. Here is the pertinent code in the `DataTableModel` class: (note that my column for check boxes is the first column, at index 0, and that my data in my array at this column is "null"). For some

```
public class DataTableModel extends AbstractTableModel
{
    private String[][] data;
    private String[] header =
    { "", "KB Name", "fpGUID" };

    public DataTableModel() throws SQLException
    {
        // ========= CONNECTS TO DB AND PULLS RESULTS ==========

        // GETS RESULTS SET CALLED "rs"

        // populate data array
        int counter = 0;
        while (rs.next())
        {
            //data[counter][0] = "sfsdfsdfs ";
            data[counter][1] = (String) rs.getObject(2);
            data[counter][2] = (String) rs.getObject(4);

            counter++;
        }
        // =====================================================

    }

@Override
public String getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
{
    return data[rowIndex][columnIndex];
}

public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col)
{
    return col == 0;
}

public Class getColumnClass(int column)
{
    if (column == 0)
    {
        return Boolean.class;
    } else
    {
        return String.class;
    }
}
```

So, it seems my `getColumnClass()` method is fine, so what is the problem? Could it be something with my "data" which I store the data for the table. Here is the data array:

Comment: This doesn't look right: `String getValueAt(...)`. This should return an Object, not a String, and in particular, if the columnIndex is 0, it should return a `Boolean` to agree with your `getColumnClass` and with your need to display an editable JCheckBox.

Comment: Oh, it should return an Object? And I tried to assign column 0 of the data array to false but I get an error because my data array is of type String. Should I make the data type if the data array to Object (I think I already tried this but was getting an error..).

Comment: You need to look at the API for [TableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html). What is the signature for the `getValueAt(...)` method? The API will tell you. As for your errors, well, you'll need to fix them, but I am 100% sure that the data of column 0 *must* be `Boolean`.

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13919878/230513).

Comment: Thank you all for your input, greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of things that jump out...

- (As has already begin pointed out) `getValueAt` appears to be declared wrong.  It should be returning `Object`.  Think about it for a second.  Your expectation is that the first column will be `boolean`, so how can you return `String` from this method...which leads to...
- Your `data` array is an array of `String`...where, again, the expectation is that the first value should be `boolean`.  Now you can actually keep this, but you will need to translate the value to `boolean` from the `getValueAt` method and back again for the `setValueAt` method...which leads to...
- You've not implemented `setValueAt`, so there is no way that the changes to the cell value can be stored
- You're also not implementing `getRowCount`, which is required, `getColumnCount`, which is required and you should implement `getColumnName`, since you actually have some.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class TestTableModel02 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestTableModel02();
    }

    public TestTableModel02() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(new JTable(new DataTableModel())));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class DataTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private Object[][] data;
        private String[] header = {"", "KB Name", "fpGUID"};

        public DataTableModel() {//throws SQLException {
            // ========= CONNECTS TO DB AND PULLS RESULTS ==========

            // GETS RESULTS SET CALLED "rs"

            // populate data array
//            int counter = 0;
//            while (rs.next()) {
//                //data[counter][0] = "sfsdfsdfs ";
//                data[counter][1] = (String) rs.getObject(2);
//                data[counter][2] = (String) rs.getObject(4);
//
//                counter++;
//            }
            // =====================================================

            data = new Object[4][3];
            data[0] = new Object[]{false, "Help", "1234"};
            data[1] = new Object[]{false, "On fire", "5648"};
            data[2] = new Object[]{false, "Drowning", "9012"};
            data[3] = new Object[]{false, "Micky Mouse", "3456"};
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return data[rowIndex][columnIndex];
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
            return col == 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
            if (column == 0) {
                return Boolean.class;
            } else {
                return String.class;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            if (columnIndex == 0) {
                if (aValue instanceof Boolean) {
                    data[rowIndex][columnIndex] = (Boolean)aValue;
                    fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.length;
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return header.length;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int column) {
            return header[column];
        }
    }
}
```

Now, there are ways you can get around the whole "first column must be boolean" issue, but to be frank, it's much less code to do it this way.

I would also, strongly, recommend that you take a look at `SwingWorker` and do all your data loading using it, otherwise you may find that your UI comes to a grinding halt while the data is begin loaded, which is generally rather unpleasant.

Take a look at...

- [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)
- [How to use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

For more details

Comment: Inside the `setValueAt()` method of `DataTableModel` class, isn't the programmer suppose to call `fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);` ?

Comment: @nIcEcOw cells, rows, you get the same effect :P

Comment: LOL :-), actually, just started reading about `JTable` now a days, never tried it before. But aren't we just changing a `single Cell` while clicking on a `JCheckBox` acting as a renderer, as against the whole `Row`, though +1 for this example :-)

Comment: Yes, it would be more efficient to use cellUpdate as the table only needs to update a single cell and re-render the entire row

Comment: Thankyou for the profound information, mate, surely will help me as I move along reading more about `JTable` and KEEP SMILING :-)

Comment: Great! These were my problems! Thank you very much for such a complete answer (by the way I did have `getRowCount()` `getColumnCount()` and `getColumnName()` implemented I just didn't post it, I should have though).