# AbstractTableModel getValueAt perfomance

Tags: java, swing, jtable, abstracttablemodel

I am newbie in `JTable`, maybe I don't understand something.

Let's suppose I have `ArrayList` of 1000 `Students` (`id, name, surname, age`). And I want to show all students in `JTable`. As far as I understood I must create `StudentTableModel` that `extends AbstractTableModel` and set `StudentTableModel` to `JTable`. Therefore we can consider `StudentTableModel` as an "adapter" between our `ArrayList` and the table. On the internet I found such example implementation of `getValueAt`:

```
 public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
      Student student = arrayList.get(row);
      switch (col) {
      case 0:
        return student.getId();
      case 1:
        return student.getName();
      case 2:
        return student.getSurname();
      case 3:
        return student.getAge();
      }
    }
```

The problem is that having 1000 students (rows) and 4 field (columns)  we will run this switch 4000 times. Please explain what I do wrong or tell about a better solution.

Comment: there couldnt be some problem with numbers of Items,

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that. If you think 4000 is a big number, don't worry, the processor doesn't consider that anything. The only way this would be a problem is if you were to perform a database query every time, even then the switch wouldn't be the problem but the actual retrieval of data. I suggest that you don't try to think about performance before you have actual proof that it's an issue.

Comment: @mKorbel Please explain what you mean.

Comment: there are two options, depends of direction 1. you would need to use array for (and then to use and override) AbstractTableModel in the case that this array is used as primary data source for/to whole programm,  2. otherwise to use DeafultTableModel, then all values are accesible from this model for/to whole program

Comment: `The problem is that having 1000 students (rows) and 4 field (columns) we will run this switch 4000 times.` In addition to Kayaman's comment, the JTable will only dispay 20-30 rows at a time so the code will only be executed 80-120 times when you scroll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Having 1000 students (rows) and 4 field (columns), we will run this switch 4000 times.*

The premise is false, but you should [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2064427/230513) to verify. `JTable` uses the [*flyweight pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) for cell [rendering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender), so only *visible* cells will be examined. This simplified [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7776211/230513) illustrates the essential mechanism. This related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13919878/230513) scales well into the thousands of rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can store students in a `Map` which maps row to student attributes.

```
Map<Integer, Object[]> students;
```

The method will look so:

```
public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
    return students.get(row)[col];
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, `Map<Key, Student>`; here is a related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9134371/230513).