# How can i put a JList object in a Jtree node in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, tree, jlist, jtree

I have this doubt, i'm using java swing, and i need to do a data tree that need display a Jlist content of a node of Jtree.

Each one in different JPanel

Comment: Your question is not clear. Also, please post the code you tried and tell us what it's doing wrong. See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It's gonna be tricky. Both JTrees and JLists work using a Component Renderer. This renderer is used to draw list / tree elements, but isn't actually added to the GUI, so event capture / element selection would need to be customized in your situation

Answer (score 2):

For the reasons suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26080383/how-can-i-put-a-jlist-object-in-a-jtree-node-in-java-swing#comment40865033_26080383), you'd need a custom `TreeCellRenderer` and `TreeCellEditor` for your [`JTree`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html).

As a less complex alternative, add a [`TreeSelectionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/treeselectionlistener.html) to your tree. In the listener, update the `ListModel` of an adjacent [`JList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) to reflect the current tree selection. Use a `GridLayout(1, 0)` for the tree and list, as shown in this related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13919878/230513) using `JTable` and `JList`.