# Preferred height of JPanel is lower then combined height of its children in table renderer

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jlabel

I have a `JTable` for which the renderer returns a `JPanel` composed of multiple `JLabel` instances. One of those `JLabel`s can contain HTML used among other things to split the output over multiple lines using `<br/>` tags.

To show the multiple lines in the table, the renderer calls in the `getTableCellRendererComponent` method

```
table.setRowHeight(row, componentToReturn.getPreferredSize().height);
```

to dynamically update the row height, based on the contents. This only works correctly if `componentToReturn` indicates a correct preferred size.

It looks however that the `getPreferredSize` returns bogus values. The preferred height of the returned component is smaller than the sum of the heights of the labels inside the component.

Here is a little program illustrating this behaviour (without using a `JTable`)

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SwingLabelTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        LabelPanel renderer = new LabelPanel();
        Component component = renderer.getComponent(false);
        //asking for a bigger component will not
        //update the preferred size of the returned component
        component = renderer.getComponent(true);
      }
    });
  }

  private static class LabelPanel {
    private final JPanel compositePanel;
    private final JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel();
    private final JLabel propertyLabel = new JLabel();

    public LabelPanel() {
      JPanel labelPanel = new JPanel();
      labelPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(labelPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

      labelPanel.add(titleLabel);
      labelPanel.add(propertyLabel);

      compositePanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      //normally it contains more components,
      //but that is not needed to illustrate the problem
      compositePanel.add(labelPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public Component getComponent( boolean aMultiLineProperty ) {
      titleLabel.setText("Title");
      if ( aMultiLineProperty ){
        propertyLabel.setText("<html>First line<br/>Property: value</html>");
      } else {
        propertyLabel.setText("Property: value");
      }

      int titleLabelHeight = titleLabel.getPreferredSize().height;
      int propertyLabelHeight = propertyLabel.getPreferredSize().height;
      int compositePanelHeight = compositePanel.getPreferredSize().height;
      if ( compositePanelHeight < titleLabelHeight + propertyLabelHeight){
        throw new RuntimeException("Preferred size of the component returned "
                                   + "by the renderer is incorrect");
      }

      return compositePanel;
    }
  }
}
```

As I am aware that the previous example is a bit far-fetched, here an example which includes a `JTable`

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class SwingTableTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(0, 1);
        JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DataResultRenderer());
        tableModel.addRow(new Object[]{new Object()});
        tableModel.addRow(new Object[]{new Object()});
        tableModel.addRow(new Object[]{new Object()});

        JFrame testFrame = new JFrame("TestFrame");
        testFrame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table));
        testFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        testFrame.setSize(new Dimension(300, testFrame.getPreferredSize().height));
        testFrame.setVisible(true);
      }
    });
  }

  private static class DataResultRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {
    private final JPanel compositePanel;
    private final JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel();
    private final JLabel propertyLabel = new JLabel();

    public DataResultRenderer() {

      JPanel labelPanel = new JPanel();
      labelPanel.setOpaque(false);
      labelPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(labelPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

      labelPanel.add(titleLabel);
      labelPanel.add(propertyLabel);

      compositePanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      //normally it contains more components,
      //but that is not needed to illustrate the problem
      compositePanel.add(labelPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
        JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, 
        boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
      titleLabel.setText("Title");

      if ( row == 2 ){
        propertyLabel.setText("<html>Single property: value</html>");
      } else {
        String text = "<html>";
        text += "First property<br/>";
        text += "Second property<br/>";
        text += "Third property:value";
        text += "</html>";
        propertyLabel.setText(text);
      }

      int titleLabelHeight = titleLabel.getPreferredSize().height;
      int propertyLabelHeight = propertyLabel.getPreferredSize().height;
      int compositePanelHeight = compositePanel.getPreferredSize().height;
      if ( compositePanelHeight < titleLabelHeight + propertyLabelHeight){
        throw new RuntimeException("Preferred size of the component returned "
                                   + "by the renderer is incorrect");
      }
      table.setRowHeight(row, compositePanel.getPreferredSize().height);
      return compositePanel;
    }

  }
}
```

I am looking for a way to update the row height of the table to ensure that the multi-line content is completely visible, without knowing up front how many lines each row will contain.

So either I need a solution to retrieve the correct preferred size, or my approach is completely wrong and then I need a better one.

Note that the above examples are simplified. In the real code, the "renderer" (the code responsible for creating the component) is decorated a few times. This means that the outer renderer is the only with access to the `JTable`, and it has no knowledge about what kind of `Component` the inner code returns.

Answer (score 2):

Because [`setRowHeight()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setRowHeight-int-) "Sets the height, in pixels, of all cells to `rowHeight`, revalidates, and repaints," the approach is unsound. Absent throwing an exception, profiling shows 100% CPU usage as an endless cascade of repaints tries to change the row height repeatedly. Moreover, row selection becomes unreliable.

Some alternatives include these:

- Use [`TablePopupEditor`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3591230/230513) to display multi-line content on request from a `TableCellEditor`.
- Update an adjacent multi-line panel from a `TableModelListener`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13919878/230513).

Comment: In my case, the contents of the table is set once, and does not change, nor is it editable. As such, the `setRowHeight()` stops looping ;-) . Dirty, but doable. I should probably have mentioned that in the question. I will now go over your links.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense; be sure to account for `rowMargin`; the result maybe L&F dependent.

Comment: I checked the links, but I cannot use any of those solutions. Anyway, I worked around it by simply ensuring that all components have the same height, and setting the height once.

Comment: I think that's a reasonable compromise.

Comment: Still wondering though why exactly the preferred size that I got with the above code sometimes is wrong, and other times not. Always hate it when my code does something I do not understand

Comment: I'm not sure; the first three calls to the renderer are correct; the exception seems to occur on the first recursive call, when the previous row is the short one.