# java swing jtable - display row index for each row

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm working on a java desktop application and I have a Swing JTable for displaying data. **I need to have a column for displaying row index for each row in the table**. I don't want to add index in the grid data. Here is the way that I'm using to fill my table:

```
private DefaultTableModel defaultTableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
defaultTableModel.setDataVector(dataArray, headerArray);
jTable.setModel(defaultTableModel);
```

Answer (score 2):

`JTable` displays what the `TableModel` tells it to display. Instead, extend `AbstractTableModel`. In your implementation of `getValueAt()`, return the row number for column zero and return the appropriate element of `dataArray` otherwise. Related examples may be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13919878/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9134371/230513).

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `row header` to the scroll pane to display numbers for each row in the table.

Any component can be added to the row header. So one solution is to add a second (custom) JTable that just displays row numbers with a custom renderer so that the number look like the column headers.

Check out [Row Table Number](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/18/row-number-table/) for an example of this approach.